# is Using JSON data is better then Querying Database when there is no security issue for data

Tags: database, json, database-design

For my new project I'm looking forward to use JSON data as a text file rather then fetching data from database. My concept is to save a JSON file on the server whenever admin creates a new entry in the database.

As there is no issue of security, will this approach will make user access to data  faster or shall I go with the usual database queries.

Comment: You should try to add some punctuation in your question

Answer (score 2):

JSON is typically used as a way to format the data for the purpose of transporting it somewhere. Databases are typically used for storing data.

Comment: That is exactly right. XML / JSON are for data-transport or formatting. Databases are for storage.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described may be perfectly sensible, but you really need to say a little bit more about your project before the community can comment on your approach.

What's the pattern of access? Is it always read-only for the user, editable only by site administrator for example?

You shouldn't worry about performance early on. Worry more about ease of development, maintenance and reliability, you can always optimise afterwards.

You may want to look at http://www.mongodb.org/. **MongoDB** is a document-centric store that uses JSON as its storage format.

Answer (score 0):

JSON in combination with Jquery is a great fast web page smooth updating option but ultimately it still will come down to the same database query.

Just make sure your query is efficient.  Use a stored proc.

JSON is just the way the data is sent from the server (Web controller in MVC or code behind in standind c#) to the client (JQuery or JavaScript)

Ultimately the database will be queried the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick with the classic method (database), because you'll face many problems with concurrency and with having too many files to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with usual database query.

If you use JSON file you'll have to sync JSON files with the DB (That's mean an extra work is need) and face I/O problems (if your site super busy).